# If $f(x) =\sin^{1200}(x) \ln(1+x)^{500}\arctan^{300}(x)$ how to find $f^{(2000)}(0)$ without Taylor series?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

I saw this challenging problem: If $f(x) =\sin^{1200}(x) \ln(1+x)^{500}\arctan^{300}(x)$ how to find $f^{(2000)}(0)$.

Applying Leibniz rule seems to be the only way to solve this, but  it quickly became a nightmare finding a pattern:

$$f'(x)=1200 \sin^{1199}(x) \ln(1+x)^{500}\arctan^{300}(x)\cos(x)+\sin^{1200}(x) 500\frac{\ln(1+x)^{499}}{1+x}\arctan^{300}(x)+300\sin^{1200}(x) \ln(1+x)^{500}\frac{\arctan^{299}(x)}{1+x^2}$$

This function becomes very messy and ugly in the first derivative so there is no way Leibniz rule is applied here.

There must be some trick since $1200+500+300=2000$.

My friend (who gave me this problem) gave a very strange proof to this problem with  the answer $2000!$ but I didn't understand his proof.

---

There is an easy way to solve this problem with Taylor's series like user170231's answer, But I want to ask is other way to solve it without Taylor series ?

Comment: Are we allowed to use l'Hospital's Rule? If yes then we can prove step by step (applying the rule to fraction $f(x) /x^k$) that $f^{(k)} (0)=0$ for all $k=1,2,\dots,1999$ and $f^{(2000)}(0)=2000!$. Note that at $k$-th step we need to apply the rule $(k-1)$ times followed by definition of derivative.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yes it is allowed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without using series expansions, we can use the general product rule.
By using the [General form of Leibniz product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule), we can write,
$$
f^{(2000)}(x)=\left(\sin^{1200}(x)\ln(1+x)^{500}\arctan(x)^{300}\right)^{(2000)} = \left(\underbrace{\underbrace{\sin(x)\cdot\sin(x)\cdot\sin(x)\cdots}_\text{1200 times}\underbrace{\ln(1+x)\cdot\ln(1+x)\cdot\ln(1+x)\cdots}_\text{500 times}\underbrace{\arctan(x)\cdot\arctan(x)\cdot\arctan(x)\cdots}_\text{300 times}}_\text{Total 2000 terms}\right)^{(2000)}\\
=\sum_{k_1+k_2+\cdots+k_{2000}=2000}\binom{2000}{k_1,k_2,\cdots,k_{2000}}\left(\prod_{j=1}^{1200}\left(\sin(x)\right)^{(k_j)}\right)\left(\prod_{j=1201}^{1700}\left(\ln(1+x)\right)^{(k_j)}\right)\left(\prod_{j=1701}^{2000}\left(\arctan(x)\right)^{k_j}\right).
$$
Now, in any given term, if one of the $k_j$ is $0$, there will either be a $\sin(x)$ or an $\ln(1+x)$ or an $\arctan(x)$ in that term, which evaluated at $0$ gives $0$. Thus, we only need to consider the terms where $k_j\ne0\forall 1\le j\le 2000$. There is only one such term, when all $k_j=1$. Thus,
$$
f^{(2000)}(0) = \binom{2000}{1,1,\cdots,1}\cos^{1200}(0)\left(\frac{1}{1+0}\right)^{500}\left(\frac{1}{1+0^2}\right)^{300}= \binom{2000}{1,1,\cdots,1} = 2000!.
$$

Comment: This is perhaps the simplest and direct approach, but I must say the expression will look formidable to many users. +1

Comment: Yes. Although the formula is intimidating, the intuition is not: if any power of $\sin x$ survives, the entire term will evaluate to zero, so the only possible nonzero terms are the ones where $\sin^{1200} x$ is differentiated $1200$ times. And then likewise for the other two factors.

Answer (score 7):

Using the series expansion of $f(x)$ is probably the intended method:

$$\sin x = x - \frac{x^3}6 + \cdots \\
\log(1+x) = x - \frac{x^2}2 + \cdots \\
\arctan x = x - \frac{x^3}3 + \cdots \\[2ex]
\implies f(x) = \left(x^{1200} + \cdots\right) \left(x^{500} + \cdots \right) \left(x^{300} + \cdots\right) = x^{2000} + \cdots$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer but Is there is other way to solve it without Taylor series ?

Comment: He somehow proved that the $f^{(n)}(0) =0 $ for all $n < 2000$ and used continuity of derivative and gave me this hint "don't try to find a pattern. think of definition ".

Comment: "Definition" makes me think he somehow leverages the derivative as a limit, possibly exploiting $\left(\dfrac{\sin x}x,\dfrac{\log(1+x)}x,\dfrac{\arctan x}x\right)\to(1,1,1)$ as $x\to0$. But that's speculation, IDK what else can be done here. Perhaps another user can figure out something clever.

Answer (score 5):

We know that $f(x)$ is smooth at $0$ (as the product of smooth functions) and that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x)/x^{2000}= \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} (\sin(x) /x)^{1200}(\ln(1+x)/x)^{500}(\arctan(x)/x)^{300}=1$$

Thus, $f(x)=x^{2000}+o(x^{2000})$ and $f^{(2000)}(0)=2000!$.

Answer (score 4):

Let us observe that $f$ is infinitely differentiable at $0$ and $f(x) /x^{2000}\to 1$ as $x\to 0$. In what follows we replace $2000$ by a symbol $p$ to reduce typing effort. The above shows that $f(x) /x^k\to 0$ for all $k=1,2,\dots, p-1$.

We can also notice by definition of derivative that $$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=0$$ Next we have via l'Hospital's Rule $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f'(x)}{2x}=\frac{1}{2}f''(0)$$ so that $f' '(0)=0$. Let's show one more step for $k=3$ and we have via two applications of l'Hospital's Rule $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x^3}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f'(x)}{3x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f''(x)}{6x}=\frac{1}{6}f'''(0)$$ so that $f' '' (0)=0$. We can continue in this manner till $k=p-1$ and get all the derivatives $f^{(k)} (0)=0$.

Finally for $k=p$ we apply l'Hospital Rule $(p-1)$ times to get $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x^p}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f'(x)}{px^{p-1}}=\dots =\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f^{(p-1)}(x)}{p!x}=\frac{f^{(p)}(0)}{p!}$$ and hence $f^{(p)} (0)=p!=2000!$.